# Get Google+ User Id when doing YouTube OAuth Process

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-plus

I am running through the OAuth process with Google+ scopes (email, profile) as well as the basic scope for the YouTube API.

If a user selects a YouTube Channel that is tied to a Google+ Page, then the Google information that I get back is for the Google+ Page (which isn't what I want)

What I want is the Google Id (and name and email) of the USER who is logged in - not the Google+ Page's info.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sign-In doesn't work that way. You get authorized to for the info of the identity signing in and only that identity. If you want info from another identity the user has to authorize your app to access that identities info or ask them to manually enter the info.

Comment: The thing is - first, you select your Google Identity and then it lists all of the YouTube channels that identify has access to and you select a Channel. So in "step 1" of the process, you are selecting a regular user identity which is why I was hoping I'd be able to get access to it.

Comment: The user has to traverse their available identities to decide who to authorize with but they only authorize access to a single identity at a time.